# Why doesn't LWP.pm work on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, perl, include, dependencies, sudo

I have a Mac Book Pro, it has Perl.

I have a script with includes.

```
use LWP ;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw{ POST };
use HTML::Form;
```

LWP so I ran (twice once as root once as normal user) [Guide I followed](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch01_03.htm)

> perl -MCPAN -e 'shell'

```
install Bundle::LWP
install HTML::Tree
install HTML::Form
```

> Warning: Cannot install HTML::Format, don't know what it is.

#### It says its missing two dependencies, but when I install them it says they are already done...?

[Pastebin showing the output of the dependencies problem](http://pastebin.com/34puKNj7)

#### When I run the script this is the error I get:

> Can't locate LWP.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.16.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at NMLRegAttack2.pl line 1.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at NMLRegAttack2.pl line 1.

Comment: HTML::Format should be HTML::Form

Comment: It's skipping everything, so what you provided is rather useless. Let's address that first. Do: 1) `cpan`, 2) `o conf build_dir_reuse 0`, 3) `o conf commit`, 4) `exit`, 5) Then try to install HTML::Entities and HTML::HeadParser again. Update the question with that output if you still have a problem.

Comment: Okay now it works... why is that off by defualt? And it also said **Do not** `o conf commit`  but I did and it works.

Comment: It should be false, and it is false by default. I don't why it was true on your system.

Answer (score 1):

build_dir_reuse is not set correctly

**Solution**

1. cpan
2. conf build_dir_reuse 0
3. o conf commit
4. exit